# How can I debug my typegraphql resolvers in VS Code?

Tags: apollo-server, vscode-debugger, typegraphql

so I got my typeorm, typegraphql, apollo-server-express, typescript endpoint up and running with resolvers, mutations and all that stuff.

Having a c# background I sometimes want to debug my endpoint when making requests to the playground to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I haven't found a setup in which vscode allows me to do that, also google wasn't much of a help.

Is it possible what i'm trying to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it using the following launch.json, maybe this helps someone else

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Example",
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "runtimeExecutable": "node",
          "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
    
          "args": ["src/index.ts", "--transpile-only", "hello"],
          
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
          "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "node_modules/**"]
        }
      ]
  }
```